# GeoNetwork + Mapproxy customized endpoints?

Tags: geonetwork, mapproxy, mapcache, wmc

I'd like to build a service that allow each user of a GeoNetwork portal or sub portal (https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/users/administrator-guide/configuring-the-catalog/portal-configuration.html) to share maps.

By default, we can share maps with OWS context, But the fact is that client applications must be modified to handle the OWS context.

Do you know a plugin or approach that can enable the publication of a per-portal or per-subportal decated sets of endpoints (WMS/WMTS/WFS)?

- Perhaps by associating MapCache/Mapproxy with GeoNetwork?

Therefore, this will allow immediate compatibility with client applications, allowing them to use simple GetCapabilities requests on standard endpoints.

Comment: An OWS Context or Web Map Context file, wouldn't call a GetCapabilities, rather it allows the sharing of maps themselves, GetMap or GetFeature requests for a certain CRS and extent.

Comment: It is unfortunate considering how useful the OGC context standards are for sharing map workspaces, that their support is limited across software.  There is WMC support in an ArcGIS plugin, and in OpenLayers 2.  We have a proof of concept for WMC support in Leaflet, and hope too to get something in QGIS too, we have no funding so will have to build it ourselves.  I'm not aware of any OWS context support in any software :(

Comment: Yes, you're right. The XML ecosystem is a great intent to manage enterprise-grade software integration. But, every change you make into a schema implies heavy work into client apps development.

Comment: From a services point of view, the use case of a context is a thematic curated list of accessible products, accessible to an application. So, every application owner only wants to get simple classic endpoints where data is available without headaches. Therefore, per-user / per-map or per-thematic dedicated endpoints are a clean way to go :-)